# Install4j task "Run executable or batch file" failing

Tags: install4j

We were using install4j 4.x and recently upgraded to version 7.0.3. In the new version the installer is failing to run the action "Run executable or batch file". It is correctly picking the executable/batch file location but can’t run it. Can you please enlighten what are we missing? One specific example is where the installer is detecting a previous installation, It tries to invoke the uninstaller, locates the uninstall.exe correctly but can’t run it. please find attached the detail of the "Run executable or batch file" action and the error during installation.